# How can I prevent duplicate of the output in python?

Tags: python

I want to make a random word, but I don't want the output to have the same word, such as a sentence is 'I want GUN GUN', I don't want GUN to repeat, but other words, such as 'I want powerful GUN'. But I don't know how to add the code so that the output has no repeated words.

```
import random
global word_list
word_list=['bunny','blue','cub','there','is','are','breakfest','the','at','name','eat','end','of','fantastic','dinner','time','go','for','I','you']
def gen_list_of_words(number_of_words, word_list):
    listwords=[]
    for i in range(number_of_words):
        listwords.append(random.choice(word_list))
    return listwords

def output_line(listwords,word_line):
    line=""
    for words in listwords:
        if random.random()< 1/((75/100)*len(words)):
            line+=words.upper()+"  "
        else:
            line+=words+"  "
        line=line[:-1]
    if word_line==0:
        line+=','
    elif word_line==1:
        line+="!"
    elif word_line==2:
        line+="."

    return line

def main():
    number_of_words=[4,6,4]
    listwords=[]
    for i in range(3):
        listwords.append(gen_list_of_words(number_of_words[i], word_list))
        print(output_line(listwords[i],i))

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this,

```
for i in range(number_of_words):
    listwords.append(random.choice(word_list))
```

you can add this code to your `gen_list_of_words` function.

```
word=random.choice(word_list)
while word in listwords:
    word=random.choice(word_list)
listwords.append(word)
```

It checks if the random word is in the sentence already, and if there's the word, it picks again.

And the final code:

```
global word_list
word_list=['bunny','blue','cub','there','is','are','breakfest','the','at','name','eat','end','of','fantastic','dinner','time','go','for','I','you']
def gen_list_of_words(number_of_words, word_list):
    listwords=[]
    for i in range(number_of_words):
        word=random.choice(word_list)
        while word in listwords:
            word=random.choice(word_list)
        listwords.append(word)
    return listwords

def output_line(listwords,word_line):
    line=""
    for words in listwords:
        if random.random()< 1/((75/100)*len(words)):
            line+=words.upper()+"  "
        else:
            line+=words+"  "
        line=line[:-1]
    if word_line==0:
        line+=','
    elif word_line==1:
        line+="!"
    elif word_line==2:
        line+="."

    return line

def main():
    number_of_words=[4,6,4]
    listwords=[]
    for i in range(3):
        listwords.append(gen_list_of_words(number_of_words[i], word_list))
        print(output_line(listwords[i],i))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def gen_list_of_words(number_of_words, word_list):
    listwords=[]
    word_list_t = word_list.copy()
    for i in range(number_of_words):
        word = random.choice(word_list_t)
        word_list_t.remove(word)
        listwords.append(word)
    return listwords
```